# Есть вопрос по owl карусели

Tags: javascript

У меня на странице может быть очень много слайдеров. Как сделать так, что бы не копировать один и тот же код множество раз, где мне надо просто id поменять? Есть главный слайдер , в котором есть слайдер поменьше, где есть одна большая картинка и маленькие картинки(при нажатии на маленькую меняется большая).

Comment: использую owl 2

Comment: Обернуть код в свою функцию, которая будет принимать id. А потом по циклу вызвать для каждого из слайдеров эту функцию, передав idшник конкретного слайдера. Наверно это "капитанский ответ", но судя по вопросу решение именно такое

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что в нём отсутствует важная деталь, без которой нельзя дать хороший ответ. Пожалуйста, редактируйте свой вопрос, добавив в него пример кода, чтобы пользователи смогли дать лаконичный ответ. Чтобы редактировать вопрос, нажмите на кнопку [Edit]. Так же можете ознакомиться с советами о том, [как задать хороший вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). - [Из очереди проверок](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/close/148072)